# Can't input upper character when to install archlinux

Tags: arch-linux

My keyboard can input upper characters by pressing `caps lock` key. However today during my first installation of arch linux, in the console I find that pressing `caps lock` key does not work!

Therefore I can't input

```
genfstab -U  /mnt  >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

I can only input

```
genfstab -u  /mnt  >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Maybe the driver for keyboard missing,so i install linux-firmware with:

```
pacstrap  /mnt linux-firmware
```

It encounter error info:

```
Possibly missing firmware for module: aic94xx
Possibly missing firmware for module: wd719x
Possibly missing firmware for module: xhci_pci
```

I made a google search and want to try with:

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/aic94xx-firmware.git
cd aic94xx-firmware
makepkg -sri

git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/wd719x-firmware.git
cd wd719x-firmware
makepkg -sri

git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/xhci_pci-firmware.git
cd xhci_pci-firmware
makepkg -sri 

mkinitcpio -p linux
```

First install the git.

```
pacstrap  /mnt  git
```

Then:

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/aic94xx-firmware.git
```

It encounter an error info:

```
git will not execute and completion _git exists.
```

I have already installed two oses in my home pc,win10+debian10,the `Caps Lock` key used normally in both os,keyboard produced by logitech (type:k120) , but it can't work during my first installation for archlinux.
How can I fix it?

Comment: are you saying that upper case `U` does not work, but all the other upper case letters work correctly?

Comment: Can you test with other upper case letters, and update the question with the results.

Comment: All character's upper case can't be typed.

Comment: None of the firmware packages you are trying to install contains keyboard drivers. What kind of keyboard do you have? Does it not have shift keys?

Comment: It is a logitech K120,it surely contain a shift key.

Comment: So it's a standard USB desktop computer keyboard. In your question, you only wanted to type a single U character in upper case. Don't you get a upper case U with shift? As to why your Caps Lock key doesn't work: maybe it has gotten remapped to something else, like a second control key?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways, depending on what tools you have in this "install" environment.

- use the readline library with bash (in emacs mode)

```
type 
g e n f s t a b space - u C-b Esc u
```

to uppercase the u (C-b means control b, Esc is the escape key).

- With vi

Create a file, perhaps in /tmp/gen, with

```
   genfstab -u  /mnt  >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

in it, put the cursor over the `u` and press `~` to change the case, type `:wq` to exit vi and then run

```
   sh -x /tmp/gen
```

to execute the command.

- With a modern bash

```
u=u   # put a lower case u in a variable
uu=${u^^}  # upper case the variable
genfstab -${uu}  /mnt  >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Comment: I have typed upper case u with vim,there are so many characters upper case to be typed,it is not a good way to solve the issue.

Comment: Do you mean that you can type upper case letters inside vim, or that  using vim to create commands using `~` is not a practical approach? Before you edited your question the implication was that this was a one-off issue you had during installation only affecting the letter U.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the "U" problem.

```
genfstab -$(echo $'\x55')  /mnt  >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

For the keyboard, I think it should work with no problem with the Linux kernel drivers. However, you should have had installed it with

```
pacstrap  /mnt base linux linux-firmware
```

You are also need to (I am assuming you are not installing it offline)

```
pacman -Suy xorg xorg-server
```

For the errors, just ignore them, unless you really need them

```
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio#Possibly_missing_firmware_for_module_XXXX
```

Finally, if you need to map your own keys look at this

```
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration
```

Good luck